# How to import file in different programming language

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-3.9

So for example in filename test.c:

```c
void blah() {
   printf("Blah");
   return 0;
}
```

and in main.py i want to import blah function from test.c which is coded in C, is it possible to import an different language in python language?
When i check python modules, sometimes i come across the module having c file.
Example:Yarl (installed from discord.py)

Comment: There are many options. You can write a C wrapper that exposes the function as a python object [Extending python with C](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html#extending-python-with-c-or-c). Or use [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes) or cython, or other python ffi (foreign function interface). You could even run the C code as a separate process and interact through some sort of api like http, soap, rpc, etc. Unfortunately, this type of question isn't a good fit for StackOverflow because of the choices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing files of different languages can be done but only in specific circumstances.

To import C files according to documentation you first compile the C code and then can use the compiled file in your code. All `.c` files in the modules folder must be compiled and many times are part of libraries that have been compiled.

You can see the documentation and guides on how to do this here: http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/python_c_extension.html